# Interfaces: require an abstract constant?

Tags: php, oop, interface

I have a class `ParentClass()`, some child-classes `ChildClass1()`, `ChildClass2()`, etc. and an interface `iChild()`. The `ChildClass()` inherits from the `ParentClass()` and implements `iChild()`:

```
class ChildClass1 
    extends ParentClass 
    implements iChild {}

class ChildClass2 
    extends ParentClass 
    implements iChild {}
```

In the `iChild()`-Interface, I would like to require, that some constants need to be filled (which are mainly identifiers and some functionality definitions). I have not found any meaning to do so, as constants may only be defined in the interface, but which are not redefinable in the implementing classes. The only workaround I found is to define some getter-functions in `iChild()`, which in turn return the necessary values, but that does not seem to be the right way to do. As I already extend from the `ParentClass()`, I also cannot use an abstract class to e.g. check the definition of the required constants in all ChildClasses.

Any ideas on how to tackle this problem?

---

*Update:* To answer a comment - with leaner and more readable I mean to following:

```
class ChildClass1 {
    const MY_NAME = "Foo Bar Name 1";
}

-- vs --

class ChildClass1 {
    public function GetMyName() {
        return "Foo Bar Name 1";
    }
}
```

I find the first example a lot more readable and understandable than the second. Unfortunatly, I currently do not have a way to enforce MY_NAME to be set by the ChildClasses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that the proper solution here is for a constant.  The very definition of a constant is that it does not change.  If each implementation of `iChild` needs to define the constant it isn't really a constant, it is a variable.  I suggest adding in the appropriate getter methods, communicating to the user that they need to supply this information in their implementation.

---

Ok, I did a little testing and it simply is not possible for a class to override a constant set by an interface it is implementing or a parent class it is extending.  Class constants appear to be checked at compile time and a fatal error is thrown if you attempt to override it.  For what you are trying to do the appropriate answer is providing getter methods in your interface.

Comment: That's how I currently implemented it, but I'd rather call a constant than a method. It's leaner and "feels more correct". Thanks for your answer anways.

Comment: How is it leaner and "feel more correct"?  There's not gonna be anyway to have different implementations define different constants without tying yourself to the implementing classes name.